# Multiple Site (Application) Windows Authentication (IIS 7)

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, windows-authentication

We have multiple web sites that need to process DOMAIN authentication in Windows. There's only one server but multiple sites.

For example:
s1.domain.com
s2.domain.com
s3.domain.com

All of which want a single sign-on. Simple, except the login dialog only can appear once.

So we need a cross web site integrated authentication.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as what I can tell, this isn't possible to do.  IE is the only one that is capable of getting close, but it seems it's a browser shortcoming.

Instead we created redirects from the s1, s2 and s3 and configured virtual applications inside of the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

I tested a same scenario recently and it worked well, I turned on Windows Authentication and impersonate=true in both sites, then once user logged in the first site, it can make a request to the second site, it then run a query against a SQL Server database, all with a same credential.

But I've been stuck when put sites in different physical servers, the credential no longer be passed to the second site so I got 401 error when sending requesting from 1st site to 2nd site. Surprisingly, it has happened only with FireFox even it's server-server request (Fiddle couldn't catch this request).